# Awk detect stdin

Tags: awk, terminal, tty, stdin

Perl, Ruby and PHP can detect stdin:

```
$ perl -e 'print -t ? "no stdin" : "stdin"'
no stdin

$ echo | perl -e 'print -t ? "no stdin" : "stdin"'
stdin

$ ruby -e 'puts $stdin.isatty ? "no stdin" : "stdin"'
no stdin

$ echo | ruby -e 'puts $stdin.isatty ? "no stdin" : "stdin"'
stdin

$ php -r 'print posix_isatty(STDIN) ? "no stdin" : "stdin";'
no stdin

$ echo | php -r 'print posix_isatty(STDIN) ? "no stdin" : "stdin";'
stdin
```

Does Awk have some way to do this? I tried ARGC but its the same in both cases:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print ARGC == 1 ? "no stdin" : "stdin"}'
no stdin

$ echo | awk 'BEGIN {print ARGC == 1 ? "no stdin" : "stdin"}'
no stdin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your perl, ruby and php examples test whether stdin exists. Your awk approach just tests whether stdin should be used.

You can use `system("tty")` in awk to do that.

Comment: Nice - looks like `system("[ -t 0 ]")` works too

Answer (score 3):

> **`ARGC`** is the number of command-line arguments present. (indexed from `1`)

In both mentioned cases the *awk* command/expression `'BEGIN {print ARGC == 1 ? "no stdin" : "stdin"}'` is considered as the 1st argument independently of whether any data was piped to the current command.

To check for the file name of the terminal connected to standard input:

```
echo "a" | awk 'BEGIN { "tty" | getline r;  print r == "not a tty"? "stdin" : "no stdin" }'
stdin

awk 'BEGIN { "tty" | getline r;  print r == "not a tty"? "stdin" : "no stdin" }'
no stdin
```